# behavior of a meromorphic function around an essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function in a punctured disc $\mathbb D^\times$ and $0$ is an essential singularity of $f(z)$. Is it possible that $f(z)$ takes all values in the extended complex plane $\hat{\mathbb C}$ in any neighborhood of $0$? That is, is it possible that $f(z)$ has a pole and also takes every finite complex value in arbitrarily small neighborhood of $0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we use the definition of "essential singularity" that doesn't require that to be an isolated singularity, then it is possible (and in fact not unusual) that a meromorphic function attains every value in $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ infinitely often in every punctured neighbourhood of the essential singularity.

Let's assume the point in question is $0$. By the mapping properties of the exponential function it easily follows that $g(z) = \exp(1/z)$ attains every value of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ infinitely often in every punctured neighbourhood of $0$. Then composing $g$ with a surjective holomorphic $h \colon \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \to \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ achieves the desired goal (using $h \circ g$). Simple examples of such $h$ are many rational functions (of order $> 1$) like $z \mapsto \frac{z(z-1)}{(z-2)(z-3)}$. So $$f(z) = \frac{e^{1/z}(e^{1/z}-1)}{(e^{1/z}-2)(e^{1/z}-3)}$$

is a concrete example for the behaviour you ask about.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, an essential singularity is an isolated singularity, so if $0$ is one of those there are no poles in some neighbourhood of $0$.  There may be infinitely many poles in $\mathbb D^\times$, but they will accumulate at the outer boundary, not at $0$.

Comment: Okay, I guess I am not using the standard definition of an essential singularity. Usually in textbooks, one considers a holomorphic function on a punctured disc and calls $0$ an essential singularity if it is neither removable or a pole. What I am asking is that if $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function from the punctured disc $\mathbb D^\times$ to the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb C}$ and it does not extend to a holomorphic function from $\mathbb D$ to $\hat{\mathbb C}$, then is it possible that the image of any small disc $\mathbb D_\epsilon^\times$ under $f$ is the whole Riemann sphere?

Comment: @Robert Israel I don't think you  read the question correctly. The OP said nothing about 0 being  a limit point of essential singularities.

Comment: Kavi: ehh, I assume $f(z)$ has only poles in $\mathbb D^\times$. It is most clear to phrase the question in terms of holomorphic map to the Riemann sphere.